# 3d setttings on ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, google-chrome, 3d

ALAS! i cannot operate any 3d application on linux ubuntu 14.04 LTS i have tried many applications on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS but they are not supported check this out this one

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/biodigital-human/agoenciogemlojlhccbcpcfflicgnaak?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

it is just nonfunctional for ubuntu , does ubuntu really do not support 3d or any 3d drivers are missing in my pc 
currently i am using integrated motherboard graphica of radeon 3000 graphics and procesor of AMD athlon 2 
if there is something missing in my system then please inform i am very new to ubuntu and i require a serious help from others please hep me